# Why does my compressed JPG have different colors from the original file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, adobe-fireworks, jpg

I have no idea at all, first of all, of image internal composition and color modes.

That said, I have a very strange problem.

These are the pictures:

[image: http://tracker.fusiondev.com.ar/themes/bavarian_dawn/images/original.jpg]

[image: http://tracker.fusiondev.com.ar/themes/bavarian_dawn/images/bg-orange.jpg]

Well, the ORIGINAL is more colorful in Firefox, but the second is like powered off (I dont know english word for that). It looks like the yellow-orange at the left center is changed.

I needed to slow the size from 1mb to about 300k, so I opened the original with Fireworks and Photoshop (ps is the second link) with the same results.

This is not a life matter, I am just curious why this happens.

If you go to http://tracker.fusiondev.com.ar and look at `wrapper` div with `Firebug` u will be able to change the background URL to the original.jpg and see what I am talking about.

Thanks!

EDIT: If you open both URLs in Firefox u will see the change inmediatly.

Comment: Which file export setting did you use? I guess you haven't embedded the color profile.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why your images look different is because of the compression you applied to the second one. The higher the compression, the more the quality degrades.

JPEG is a [lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) format, meaning there is loss of image information during the compression (a sacrifice needed to make the file smaller). For example, this is the same image saved with an increasing compression:

[image] [image] [image]

Notice that it's not just the sharpness that gets affected, the colors suffer as well. Unfortunately, the only way to not lose colors (at all) is to use a lossless compression format, such as PNG. But, this results in a much bigger image. You can still play around with the JPEG compression modes. Two thing you should try: **Using sRGB as the colorspace** (optimized for web colors), and **Progressive** compression. Depending on your final size, you could get somewhere decent with those.

Comment: Thanks for the time in the answer. Seems that the problem was something related to Embedded Profile in Save for Web in Photoshop. I marked it, and the problem solved. Please refresh the links. I read in another question while searching for it, and seems that only FF supported it, but it wasnt marked before, so I dont know.

Comment: @Jorge Glad to hear that! You can also answer your own question with that information you mention, it might be very helpful for others.